# Two domains on the same vBulletin forum

Tags: vbulletin

Is it possible to have two domains point to the same vBulletin forum and share the logins?

For example my forum is located on some.subXXXdomain.com, but i also want to park and point the YYYdomain.com on the same forum.

I know how to do this but the problem is that when i login through YYYdomain.com, it just ask me to login again.

I think the problem is a domain-specific cookie.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

> I think the problem is a domain-specific cookie.

You're right, vBulletin will not allow you to use multi domains.

I think, the only way to use multi-domain is to hack the code, check [this mod @vborg](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=254197) as an example (vb4)

(But I would not recommend you this mod as long it's a very old mod and it's currently "Not Supported" and "Is in Beta Stage")

Alternatively for "multi-domain + single board " you could use url rewriting, check this if you 're using apache2 : [rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

This only provides a kind of redirection for your users, not a real "multi-domain" access.

Also, be aware that a regular vBuletin license allows you to use only one domain. So basically : 2 domains => 2 licenses.